# Rails has_one with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-one

In my app there are `Athletes`... athletes can have many sports.

Athlete:

```
has_many :sports, :through => :user_sports
has_one :primary_sport, conditions: ["user_sports.primary = ?", true], class_name: "Sport"
has_many :user_sports
```

UserSport:

```
class UserSport < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :athlete_id, :sport_id, :primary

  belongs_to :athlete
  belongs_to :sport
end
```

I am trying to be able to pull back the `primary_sport` as a Sport object instead of the `user_sport` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you pull your sports objects :through user_sports, you should pull your primary_sport object :through user_sports as well.

```
has_one :primary_sport, :through => :user_sports, conditions: ["user_sports.primary = ?", true], class_name: "Sport"
```

Comment: Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180847/1747491) about the removal of `conditions` in favor of using `-> { where }` in Rails 4.0.