# Rails4 ActiveRecord has_one :conditions key removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-one

I am converting a RoR3.2 app to v4.2.  In some models we have this construct:

```
  # A correspondent can have only one currently active client role or
  # it may have none.
  has_one           :active_client,   :class_name => 'Client', 
                    :conditions => IsActiveRow
```

I am getting this error:

```
      Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class,
 :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :dependent, :primary_key,
 :inverse_of, :required, :as, :foreign_type
 (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

Which is raised here:

```
      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support
/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:75:in `block in assert_valid_keys'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support
/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:73:in `each_key'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support
/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:73:in `assert_valid_keys'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib
/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:82:in `validate_options'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib
/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:62:in `initialize'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib
/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:47:in `new'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record
/associations/builder/association.rb:47:in `create_builder'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec
/bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib
/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:35:in `build'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/libexec/
bundle/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/
active_record/associations.rb:1385:in `has_one'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/app/models
/orm_active_record/correspondent.rb:14:in `<class:Correspondent>'

      /home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/proforma/app/models
/orm_active_record/correspondent.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
. . .
```

Now, I looked at the docs and, sure enough, :conditions is removed as a key for has_one associations in Rails4.0.0 while it is present in 3.2.0.  So, my questions are:

Where did the has_one :conditions => key go?
When was its deprecation announced?
Where is its deprecation announced?
What is the replacement?

P.S.  On the off chance that somebody decided that `has_one :conditions =>` should be `has_many :conditions =>`  I tried switching the method name and got the same error.  Now the edge rails associations documents still list `:conditions` as a valid key for `has_many` and yet I get the same error.  What is going on?

From Rails Upgrade Guide:

> Rails 4.0 has deprecated the old-style hash based finder API. This
>   means that methods which previously accepted "finder options" no
>   longer do. For example, Book.find(:all, conditions: { name: '1984' })
>   has been deprecated in favor of Book.where(name: '1984')

As far as I can determine this is the only mention of the deprecation anywhere.  There is no mention that I could find in the `ActiveRecord` documentation for 3.2.13 where `:conditions` is still present and there is no mention of the change in 4.0.2 where `:conditions` is simply gone.

Comment: 'each_key do |k|'
'      unless valid_keys.include?(k)'
'        raise ArgumentError.new("Unknown key: #{k.inspect}.'
            Valid keys are:   #{valid_keys.map(&:inspect).join(', ')}")
        end
      end
    end'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [official guide to upgrading rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0) the deprecation is mentioned. In general, `where` is the replacement for `conditions`. It should be passed as a lambda.

In your case, it would look like:

```
has_one :active_client, -> { where IsActiveRow }, :class_name => 'Client'
```

Comment: The 'where' doesn't work like 'conditions' did - been hours trying to fix one simple case.  Is there a gem that brings back the "conditions" block that worked?

Comment: it does word as expected `has_one :related, -> { where("whatever sql you'll write there will apply") }`