# How does one create a `has_one` relationship between two models using a join table/model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one-through

**TL;DR**: How does one create a `has_one` *association* using `through` *join table* and vice-versa a `belongs_to` *through*?

**Context**: I have two models, `ProcessLog` and `Encounter`. `ProcessLog`, as the name (somewhat) suggests, saves log of a single run (corresponding to a row in DB) of an external process (which is run multiple times). On the other hand, `Encounter` is a model that keeps track of some information X. `Encounter`s can be produced either internally or as a result of a successful execution of the external process mentioned earlier. What it entails is that *not all* `Encounter`s have an associated `ProcessLog` and *not all* `ProcessLog`s have an associated `Encounter`. However, If there is a `ProcessLog` for an `Encounter`, this is a *1:1 relationship*. An `Encounter` *cannot* have more than one `ProcessLog` and a `ProcessLog` cannot belong to more than one `Encounter`. From DB design perspective, this is an `optional relationship` (I hope I haven't forgotten my lessons). In a database, this would be modelled using a join table with `encounter_id` as the *primary key* and `process_log_id` as the *foreign key.*

**Rails**: In Rails, 1:1 relationships are generally modelled *without* using a join table and the `belongs_to` table generally having a *foreign key* to the other table. So in my case, this would be `encounter_id` in `process_logs` table.

**Problem**: With traditional Rails approach of `has_one` and `belongs_to`, this will result in many rows in `process_logs` table with `NULL` values for `encounter_id` column. Now there are pros and cons to this approach by Rails, however, that is not my intention to discuss here. Yes, it will keep the table structure simple, however, in my case it breaks the semantics and also introduces lots of `NULL` values, which I don't consider a good approach. And is also the reason why a join table exists for optional relationships.

**What have I done so far?**: There aren't a whole lot of helpful documents I could find on this topic, except for the following two linked documents, though they have their own issues and don't solve my problem.

1. [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445058/rails-has-one-with-join-table) The approach here is using has_many for the join model, whereas I have only one
2. [Discussion on RoR](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/has-one-relationship-through-join-table-orphaned-records-on-update/50822) Similarly, it is using has_many and yet somehow talks about has_one

I created a join model called `EncounterProcessLog` (which has `belongs_to` for both `ProcessLog` and `Encounter`) and then a `has_one ..., through:` on the other two models, but Rails is looking for a many-to-many association and of course looking for `encounter_id` on `process_logs` table.

**Question**: How can I achieve what I intend to achieve here? Something on the lines of (non-working) code below:

```rb
class Encounter:
    has_one :process_log, through: :encounter_process_logs

class ProcessLog:
    belongs_to :encounter, through: :encounter_process_logs # This may be incorrect way of specifying the relationship?

class EncounterProcessLog:
    belongs_to :encounter
    belongs_to :process_log # May be this should be a has_one?
```

I hope someone is able to guide me in the right direction. Thanks for reading so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of for doing this is:

```
class Encounter:
  has_one :encounter_process_log
  has_one :process_log, through: :encounter_process_log

class ProcessLog:
  has_one :encounter_process_log
  has_one :encounter, through: :encounter_process_log

class EncounterProcessLog:
  belongs_to :encounter
  belongs_to :process_log
```

This would return the `process_log` for `encounter` and vice versa which is what you want probably.

Comment: That does solve the problem and do what I want.